# WaterMark using c#

Tags: c#

I am working on a Kiosk application. There is a Maintenance mode in my application. When my application enters into Maintenance mode, i want to show the user a watermark "Maintenance Mode Commenced".

I want this watermark to be shown through out my desktop. No matter what form is in focus. Is this possible ? Any ideas....

Note : This is Windows application using c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your OS is Vista or Win7, can't you make a create a window that toplevel + translucent + maximized? Then the entire screen can say "MAINTENANCE MODE" in large friendly letters.

[Here's some C# code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/2D-Graphics/BlendAlpha.htm) that might help. I *think* what you want to do is called "alpha blending". (Haven't done it myself.)

[Here's some more](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/DrawTransparentImageUsingAB10102005010514AM/DrawTransparentImageUsingAB.aspx).

[This may be best](https://web.archive.org/web/20141227200000/http://bobpowell.net/transcontrols.aspx), I'm not positive.

Answer (score 0):

attach to the paint event of each form (maybe create a base form for all other forms to inherit)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx

you can draw your image using the graphics object provided in the handler.

Take a look at the first answer with code here:

http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/118600-how-eliminate-tiling-windows-forms-background-images

Comment: So what if when there are no forms or when some other application is on focus ? FYI, my application will run in background.

Comment: sorry if i haven't understood properly. How can this code help me for my requirement. I want to show watermark irrespective of the forms and even when no forms in focus..